# Node.js use a function from a site

Tags: javascript, node.js

let's say there is a site that has a function like
doSomething();

I want to make a code which opens the site and uses the function like chrome's f12 console in node.js if it's possible

Comment: What? What research have you done so far? Any code written?

Comment: That'll be alot of work, so could you please explain what you're actually trying to do and what `doSomething()` will do since these kind of questions often come from problems that can be solved easier in a completely different way than trying to run functions on external sites.

Comment: for example you could fetch the page content and scrape the javascript part and `eval` it in node (not much recommended), else you can use a headless browser like phantomjs to load the web page and mainpulate it as if it is in a real browser